# The minCompileSdk (31) specified in dependency's AAR metadata is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion(30),app crashes in android12 in RN

Tags: android, react-native, crash, android-12

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZwfn.jpg)

App crashes randomly - only in Android version12. Works fine for other versions.

App is installing in the device successfully for Android version 12 also. But it gets crashed while trying to open it.

Tried many solutions posted here. But nothing worked for me.

Is there anything we need to update in order to work with android version 12.

```
Here is some of the solutions i followed.

In android/app/build.gradle file


def work_version = "2.5.0"  ===>changed it to 2.7.1
    implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version") {
        force = true
    }
`
In android/build.gradle file

`
configurations.all {
       resolutionStrategy {
           // Remove this override in 0.65+, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
           force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
       }
   }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply update your `compileSdkVersion` in `android/app/build.gradle` to 31